# Linking image and title with URL

Tags: html, css, image, url

Good Evening,

I haven't probably been very clear in my explanation, so I have edited!

I have an image (which if you click takes you to a website). What I ALSO need is the text underneath that image) to also link to the same website. I don't want them to be 2 separate links, they need to be joined some how.

A good example is the BBC News where you can click EITHER the image or the text and it diverts you to the relevant URL.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "image1">
<a href = 
"https://wwww.this isamade uplink"> 
<img src="2.jpeg" width="150" height="200" alt="Made up image name" 
>Test to display
</a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.image1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 200px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies. Basically a user should be able to click either the image or title of the image (which is displayed underneath the image) and it will take them to the external website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-indent` , `display` and `float`.

- `display` for `a` , so it can wrap a floatting element and apply `text-indent`
- `float` for the `img` , so it does not react to `text-indent`, only the text and inline non floatting element will be concerned.

Live example :

```css
.image1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -100vw;/* hudge value sending text and inline tags far outside the screen */
}

.image1 a img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="image1">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200" width="150" height="200" alt="Made up image name">Testing
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was the 'correct' way to do it. However, if you want give them both the same url and only use one, you can simply wrap your `a tag` around both the title and the image. This will link both to whatever URL is in your `#URL` placeholder.

```css
.image1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 0px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 }
 
 .title-name {
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 top: 200px;
 left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#URL"><img src="https://www.mooreseal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dummy-image-square.jpg" width="150" height="200" alt="alt-text" title="title on hover" class="image1">
   <h3 class="title-name">Title</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @user17183913 Please see the adjusted code. I saw you edited your question, so this is my new answer.